# How to subtract sequential numbers in a list

Tags: r

I have some text in a dataframe as follows

**Input**

```
rownumber  CStage
1           38-40cm
2           27-22
3           32cm and 40cm
```

I want to subtract the two numbers in each `CStage` with the output being

**Desired output**

```
rownumber  CStage
1           2
2           5
3           8
```

I have used `stringr::str_extract_all(df$CStage,"\\d{2}")`

which gives me a list with each element containing two numbers

```
[[1]]
[1] "38" "40"

[[2]]
[1] "27" "22"

[[3]]
[1] "32" "40"
```

How can I then subtract the two numbers (to get a positive output)

Comment: `sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(df$CStage,"\\d{2}"), function(x) diff(as.numeric(x)))` should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cath mentioned in the comments you could use `sapply`, convert it into numeric and take `diff`erence between them.

```
num_list <- stringr::str_extract_all(df$CStage,"\\d{2}")
abs(sapply(num_list, function(x) diff(as.numeric(x))))
#[1] 2 5 8
```

Comment: lol thanks for the credit ;-). Anyway, I didn't put `abs` so my code was only half-answering the Q ;-)

Comment: but that was major part of the answer, so you deserve it ;-)

Comment: and the hardest part ^^ ;-p :'D

Comment: Thanks both. By the way the abs should be in front of diff as in abs(diff( ...Worked perfectly when I did that. Cheers

Comment: no it doesn't matter if you call abs on the whole vector once or on every element inside sapply. possibly it's faster than called around sapply as provided by @RonakShah .

Answer (score 1):

You can also `sort` and then use diff.

```
sapply(regmatches(df1$CStage, gregexpr("\\d+", df1$CStage)), function(x)diff(sort(as.numeric(x))))
#[1] 2 5 8
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) strapply** This can be done compactly using `strapply` in gsubfn.  Define a regular expression such that for each element of `CStage` it extracts the two numbers in the capture groups passing them to the anonymous function defined in formula notation returning the absolute value of the difference.

```
library(gsubfn)

transform(DF, CStage = strapply(CStage, 
                                "(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)", 
                                ~ abs(as.numeric(x) - as.numeric(y)),
                                simplify = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
  rownumber CStage
1         1      2
2         2      5
3         3      8
```

**2) Base R** A base R solution can be obtained by replacing the non-digits with spaces in `CStage` and them reading it using `read.table` to create a data frame having V1 and V2 columns.  Subtract those columns and take the absolute value.

```
transform(DF, CStage = with(read.table(text = gsub("\\D", " ", CStage)), abs(V1-V2)))
```

giving:

```
  rownumber CStage
1         1      2
2         2      5
3         3      8
```

**3) dplyr/tidyr** A solution using dplyr and tidyr using a similar approach to (2) is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  separate(CStage, into = c("V1", "V2"), sep = "\\D+", 
    extra = "drop", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(CStage = abs(V1 - V2)) %>%
  select(rownumber, CStage)
```

giving:

```
  rownumber CStage
1         1      2
2         2      5
3         3      8
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
rownumber,CStage
1,38-40cm
2,27-22
3,32cm and 40cm"

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```